# Discord Bot Arg to self and not for all users?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im struggling to figure out how to make my bot only react to my own message, or my own @ when using the command /verification

The bot currently will allow all users to verify anyone on the server, How would i stop this? Allow only the user who typed it to be verified, and disallow other users?

```
@bot.slash_command()
async def verification(ctx, arg: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send("Welcome to the server!")
    test = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="test" )
    unverified = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="untest")
    await arg.add_roles(test)
    await arg.remove_roles(unverified)
```

Still in the learning stages of learning, Apologies if this is so basic

I tried using ctx and removing arg completely but the bot does not recognize ctx.add_roles instead wants arg.add_roles

Comment: Always add a tag for the language you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason "the bot does not recognize ctx.add_roles instead wants arg.add_roles" is because `arg` is set to the class `discord.Member`.
[Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member)

As for what you want the command to do, you don't actually need to take an argument. Just use `ctx.author`

```
@bot.slash_command()
async def verification(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Welcome to the server!")
    test = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="test" )
    unverified = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="untest")
    await ctx.author.add_roles(test)
    await ctx.author.remove_roles(unverified)
```